# Request code for facebook sign in and google plus sign in

Tags: android, firebase, facebook, google-plus-signin

I had posted this question 2 days ago.
[onActivityResult method for both google+ and facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61363490/onactivityresult-method-for-both-google-and-facebook)

And I thought that maybe I can create two request codes, one for facebook and one for google + and then in onActivityResult method, I can create a switch case or else if statement using the request codes. But i don't know how to do that exactly. How can I get signIn intent for facebook. Can someone help me with that line of code, if what I am thinking can actually work ...

```
public abstract class google_abstract extends Activity {

    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    FirebaseAuth auth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.d("Success", "Login");

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    int RC_SIGN_IN_G = 0;
    int RC_SIGN_IN_F = 0;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    public void signIn_g() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN_G);
    }

    **public void signIn_f(){
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN_F);
    }**

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN_G) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }

        else if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN_F) {
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data );
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            startActivity(new Intent(this, tags.class));
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.w("Google Sign In Error", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            //            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // Check for existing Google Sign In account, if the user is already signed in
        // the GoogleSignInAccount will be non-null.
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if (account != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, tags.class));
        }
        super.onStart();
    }

    private void handleFacebookToken(AccessToken accessToken)
    {
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    FirebaseUser myuserobj=auth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(myuserobj);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"could not register to firebase",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser myuserobj) {

        String e_mail= myuserobj.getEmail();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are storing the same int (here 0) so the onActivityResult will always go in the first if statement. 
Solution - 
Firstly you need to take  integer values globally like this

```
int RC_SIGN_IN_G = 0;
```

For google you need to have request code and then fetch it in onActivityResult and check and for fb  include this line before the super call

```
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

and remove fb request code from onActivityResult
to call fb login you need to find the fb login button by its id and attach the callback listener

Final Code of onActivityResult is here

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    //include this too
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN_G) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}
```

**EDIT FB LOGIN CODE ADDED**
for google leave it the same  for fb use this
fb login code

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button); 
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        // App code
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // App code
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        // App code
    }
});
```

Comment: And then, what method should I call in the onClickListener of the google and fb buttons in the main activity ?